# How Zookeeper can handel race conditions? Please explain in details

Tags: apache-zookeeper, race-condition

This is from Zookeeper:
Coordination services are notoriously hard to get right. They are especially prone to errors such as race conditions and deadlock. The motivation behind ZooKeeper is to relieve distributed applications the responsibility of implementing coordination services from scratch.

Can anyone explain me in details how race conditions works in Zookeeper when 2 users trying to acquire the lock at same time in application developed in the zookeeper.

Answer (score 1):

ZooKeeper uses the `zab` algorithm. You can read more about it here: https://distributedalgorithm.wordpress.com/2015/06/20/architecture-of-zab-zookeeper-atomic-broadcast-protocol/

Comment: This really helps to understand it further.